# LINQ Concat nested queries sorting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following code:

```
var comp = db.Companies.Select(x => new
        {

            topid = x.ID_comp,
            hill = ((from company in db.Companies
                    where x.ID_comp > company.ID_comp
                    orderby company.ID_comp
                    select new { h = company.ID_comp.ToString() })
                    .Concat((
                    from company in db.Companies
                    where x.ID_comp > company.ID_comp
                    orderby company.ID_comp descending
                    select new { h = company.ID_comp.ToString() })))
                    .Select(y => y.h)
        });
```

The task is to build "pyramids" of ids for each company's id: `121` for `3`, `12321` for `4` and so on (if there are companies with id's like 1, 2, 3 4). The idea of the given query is to take all ids that are less than current in 2 sets and then concatenate them, ordering the second set in descending order (the top of the pyramid duplicates, but I'll return to it later).

The problem is that the `order by` clause is not performed for each set separately, and at the end I get something like `1 2 3 1 2 3` for a company with id 4. How can I order the nested queries in different orders?

UPD1: The data I work with:

Table `db.Companies`

```
ID_comp | name
--------------------
   1    |Don_avia  
   2    |Aeroflot  
   3    |Dale_avia 
   4    |air_France
   5    |British_AW
```

Output:

```
1:
2: 1 1
3: 1 2 1 2
4: 1 2 3 1 2 3
5: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

UPD2: Resulting query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID_comp] AS [ID_comp], 
[Project3].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project3].[C1] AS [C2]
FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM  (SELECT 
         CAST( [Extent2].[ID_comp] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID_comp] > [Extent2].[ID_comp]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
         CAST( [Extent3].[ID_comp] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ID_comp] > [Extent3].[ID_comp]) AS [UnionAll1] ) AS [Project3]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID_comp] ASC, [Project3].[C2] ASC
```

Comment: Could you share some example input and output data?

Comment: Consider adding a specific tag (e.g. EF, EF Core etc.) to the question, because in general LINQ to Objects the query should work correctly as is, so apparently this is a specific query provider issue.

Comment: @Tvde1  I updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've hit EF6 query translation bug - ordering of `.Concat` (SQL `UNION ALL`) subqueries is ignored.

The workaround I've found is to append fake limiting operator like `Take(int.MaxValue)` to the subqueries, which is causing EF6 to consider the orderings:

```
hill =
    (from company in db.Companies
     where x.ID_comp > company.ID_comp
     orderby company.ID_comp
     select new { h = company.ID_comp.ToString() }
    ).Take(int.MaxValue)
    .Concat(
    (from company in db.Companies
     where x.ID_comp > company.ID_comp
     orderby company.ID_comp descending
     select new { h = company.ID_comp.ToString() }
    ).Take(int.MaxValue))
    .Select(y => y.h)
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ID_comp] AS [ID_comp],
    [Project5].[C2] AS [C1],
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT
        [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1],
        1 AS [C2]
        FROM  (SELECT TOP (2147483647)
            [Project1].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Extent2].[ID_comp] AS [ID_comp],
                 CAST( [Extent2].[ID_comp] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[ID_comp] > [Extent2].[ID_comp]
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[ID_comp] ASC
        UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP (2147483647)
            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT
                [Extent3].[ID_comp] AS [ID_comp],
                 CAST( [Extent3].[ID_comp] AS nvarchar(max)) AS [C1]
                FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent3]
                WHERE [Extent1].[ID_comp] > [Extent3].[ID_comp]
            )  AS [Project3]
            ORDER BY [Project3].[ID_comp] DESC) AS [UnionAll1] ) AS [Project5]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID_comp] ASC, [Project5].[C2] ASC
```

Comment: Pure magic, it works. Thank you!
Before you answered I found another option — creating fields for each of subqueries and then concatenating them into a single field. But it can barely be considered aa workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
var comp = db.Companies.Select(x => new
{
    topid = x.ID_comp,
    hill = ((from company in db.Companies.OrderBy(y => y.ID_comp)
        where x.ID_comp > company.ID_comp
        select new { h = company.ID_comp.ToString() })
        .Concat((
        from company in db.Companies.OrderByDescending(y => y.ID_comp)
        where x.ID_comp > company.ID_comp
        select new { h = company.ID_comp.ToString() })))
        .Select(y => y.h)
    });
```

Comment: If you meant `(y => y.ID_comp)` it doesn't change anything — the ordering still works as it did.